# Hera: Multiple Nvidia drivers installed (?) How to clean up

Tags: nvidia

[image: How to clean up multiple Nvidia drivers in Hera.]

I saw that these were "free" in the AppCenter, so I clicked on them all. The next boot resulted in the black screen several people experience. I managed to (finally) get back to a working system, but don't ask me how. So, (1) is it possible to get rid of them from the list shown in the figure and (2) how do I know if I am using the best driver for my video card (Nvidia GEForce GTX 570)  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following command will remove the proprietary Nvidia driver:

```
sudo dpkg -P $(dpkg -l | grep nvidia-driver | awk '{print $2}')
sudo apt autoremove
```

This will install most recent nvidia driver

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Currently, it doesn't appear possible to hide the drivers.
   Checkout the related [issue #247](https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/247) and [issue #1068](https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/1068) on the AppCenter's issue tracker which have to do with this.
2. I recommend installing the latest Nvidia drivers that support your graphics card.
   I have similar drivers available on my laptop and use the `nvidia-driver-390` package which works very well.